# Problem with refreshing after editing in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I have a very weird problem. I have the same solution for all my slices and it doesn't work only for projects. The console.log first returns a new object, but then somehow old. I will show you the code and then images of console.log.

The edit action

```js
.addCase(
        editProject.fulfilled,
        (state: ProjectState, action: PayloadAction<Project>) => {
          state.all = state.all.map((project) => project._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : project)
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.hasError = false;
        }
      )
```

ProjectShow component

```js
const ProjectsShow: React.FC = () => {
    const { projectLink } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const { isLoading, hasError, errMessage } = useAppSelector((state) => state.projects);
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(loadProjects());
    }, [dispatch]) ;
    
    const projects = useSelector(selectAllProjects);
   
   
    if(isLoading) {
      return (
        <Loading />
      )
    } 
    if(hasError) {
      return <Error message={errMessage!} />;
    }
    const project = projects.find(({ subpageLink }) => subpageLink === projectLink);
    console.log(project)
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <Project project={project!} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Console logs

[image: Console logs]

Comment: `console.log` shows current state of the object, not when it's logged. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(project))`

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Still first one is new object and then old @KonradLinkowski

Comment: I believe that you are two objects with the same `subpageLink` or something like this

Comment: the worst thing here is that I have the same in orders, services, technologies and there all working good